# How to properly configure AutoDetectParser in Tika?

Tags: java, apache-tika

I'm using Tika to extract text from different types of files. So I use ''AutoDetectParser`` parser however it looks like that its registery is empty. I have the following code and it returns an empty list (both third and forth line).

```
 Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
 ParseContext con = new ParseContext();
 System.out.println(parser.getSupportedTypes(con)));
 System.out.println(" parsers "+parser.getParsers());
```

How should I properly configure the AutoDetectParser that it can call the proper Parser?

Comment: That's normally caused by having forgotten to include the `tika-parsers` jar on your runtime classpath, along with the dependencies. Are you *absolutely certain* that you've got those jars present and readable on your runtime classpath?

Comment: And did you try checking what parsers your install has, as [detailed in the Tika troubleshooting guide](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/Troubleshooting%20Tika#Identifying_what_Parsers_your_Tika_install_supports), along with [Identifying parsers that failed to be loaded as per the troubleshooting guide](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/Troubleshooting%20Tika#Identifying_if_any_Parsers_failed_to_be_loaded)?

Comment: thanks. the problem was for the service files, they were missing.

Answer (score 2):

Promoting a comment to an answer - you don't normally need to! As long as you have *at runtime* the Tika Core and Tika Parsers jars, along with their required dependencies, then the default [TikaConfig object](http://tika.apache.org/1.9/api/org/apache/tika/config/TikaConfig.html) will auto-detect and auto-load them all for you

If for some reason you've missed some jars at runtime, or you've been messing about repackaging Tika and lost some service files, then you'll want to follow the instructions on the [Apache Tika troubleshooting wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/Troubleshooting%20Tika), especially around [Identifying what Parsers your Tika install supports](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/Troubleshooting%20Tika#Identifying_what_Parsers_your_Tika_install_supports) and [Identifying if any Parsers failed to be loaded](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/Troubleshooting%20Tika#Identifying_if_any_Parsers_failed_to_be_loaded)

(If you want to do non-standard things, such as exclude certain parsers, or force certain parsers, or make parsers handle non-standard mime types, then you need a custom Tika Config. Normally you'd do that with a `tika-config.xml` file, see [here on the Tika wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/CompositeParserDiscussion) for what you can do)